# Getting no more than 2 categories shown and last one to remove ending slash

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to show at most 2 categories per post in wordpress and managed to do so, just that don't know how could I detect the second one.

```
<?php
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $terms  = get_terms( 'directory_categories', 'orderby=name&hide_empty=1&hierarchical=0' ); 
// I am getting the categories
    $i = 0;
    $len = count($terms); // counting the categories
    foreach($terms as $term) {
// terms is an array of objects (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms)
      $i++;
      if ($i < 3) {
        //if it reached second loop then displays with '/'
        $array[] = $term->name;
        $limit = count($array);
      ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, 'directory_categories' ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>/
    <?php
      // else if it reached second loop and second loop is 2 then it should omit the slash
    } elseif($i < 3 && i == 2) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, 'directory_categories' ); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a>
    <?php } else { } ?>
<?php } ?> <!-- end foreach -->
endwhile;
?>
```

CURRENT OUTPUT is

```
Category 1 / Category 2/
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT is without the ending slash

```
Category 1 / Category 2
```

I am very sure that logic is wrong, please let me know where am I mistaking.

Comment: The conditions in your elseif statement are never true, because you test for `$i < 3` again.

Comment: @klasske Agree, I am thinking on how to solve this for about 4 hours. and very sure is quite easy, just that I am blurred today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code instead (i've put comments so you can easily maintain it):

```
<?php 
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $tax = 'directory_categories'; // your taxonomy
    $total = 2; // number of categories to show for each post
    $sep = ' / '; // separator you want to use

    $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), $tax);
    if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
        $terms = array_values($terms);
        foreach ($terms as $key => $term) {
            echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->slug, $tax) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            if ($key < $total - 1 && count($terms) >= $total) {
                echo $sep;
            }
            if ($key == $total - 1) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Now it's echoing only one category with slash: Category 1 /

Comment: I've edited my comment - use the code above, it should do what you need.